# I've had this lighting bug for quite sometime now. Can't figure out how to resolve it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I got a new computer awhile ago, there's this bug whenever I play that makes everything look bright, even if there's no torches down. It may seem like a good thing, but when mobs are spawning around you and you can't see light levels, it kind of sucks. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: from outside at night]

[image: From a cave]

[image: Specs]

Answer (score 3):

This is allbright and it's a feature in optifine, some resource packs, and a few mods.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have somehow enabled Fullbright. Go into your settings and change your brightness to any brightness and then change it back to what you normally have your brightness on. This should fix the issue.